# Generic modeling of an energy supply chain with Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling, systemdynamics

I have been working with Anylogic for about 6 months now and my goal is to model a generic energy supply chain for an energy demand (e.g. storm and heat for a house). As a result I want to evaluate how suitable the components in the energy supply chain are to meet the energy demand.
My idea would be to model the components (Ex. PV->Battery Storage->House) as agents. I would have modeled the energy flow in the agents with SD and individual events of the components (e.g. charging and discharging at the battery) via state diagrams.

Currently I have two problems:

1. Which possibilities are there to create a variable interconnection of my components (agents). For example, if I do not want to evaluate the scenario PV->Battery Storage->House, but PV->Electrolysis->Tank->Fuel Cell->House. My current approach would be to visually connect the agents with ports and connectors and then pass input and output variables for DS calculation via set and get functions. Are there other possibilities, e.g. to realize such a connection via an input Excel? I have seen a similar solution in the video: "How to Build a True Digital Twin with Self-Configuring Models Using the Material Handling Library" by Benjamin Schumann, but I am not sure if this approach can be applied to SD.
2. To evaluate the energy supply chain, I would like to add information to the energy flow, for example the type (electricity, heat), generation price (depending on which components the energy flow went through) and others. Is there a way to add this information to a flow in SD? My current approach would be to model the energy flow as an agent population with appropriate parameters and variables. Then agents could die when energy is consumed or converted from electricity to heat type. However, I don't know if this fits with the SD modeling of the energy flow.
   Maybe you can help me with my problems? I would basically be interested in the opinion of more experienced Anylogic users if my approaches would be feasible or if there are other or easier approaches. If you know of any tutorial videos or example models that address similar problems, I would also be happy to learn from them.

Best
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a model that combine agent-based and system dynamics approaches with Agents populating the stocks (in your case energy that then gets converted into heat) depending on their connection. There is an example of AB-SD combination model in 'Example' models and I also [found one on cloud.anylogic.com](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/7b79f6ce-df83-4e90-97aa-7dcfad1eb97f?mode=SETTINGS), although it is from a different domain.

Perhaps if you can put together a simple example and share then I'll be able to provide more help.